# ArcPy conversion: use SQL filter when converting data?

Tags: arcpy, postgresql, sql, convert, dwg

In a standalone Python script, I want to use `arcpy.conversion.ExportCAD` to convert a PostgreSQL table to a .dwg file. However, I don't want to convert the entire table, just a small geographical part of it which can be defined as a WKT polygon in an SQL SELECT query. How can I embedd the SQL into the code below:

```
import arcpy

wkt = r'Polygon ((372388 166120, 372388 166742, 373122 166742, 373122 166120, 372388 166120))'
sql = fr"SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geom, 'SRID=27700;{wkt}')"

arcpy.conversion.ExportCAD(fr"'folder\database.sde\db_name.schema.table'", "DWG_R2018", fr"folder\output.dwg", "Ignore_Filenames_in_Tables", "Overwrite_Existing_Files", None)  # how can I include the SQL filter in this command?
```

Comment: Lots of ways possible. I'd make a QueryLayer, then use the QL as the input source

Comment: That wkt is a square envelope right? Have you tried setting `arcpy.env.extent = some_extent`?

Comment: the WKT is a simple square yes, but the dataset is far bigger than that extent. Will setting the `env` extent apply to the dataset too during conversion?

Comment: @Vince thanks but I'm struggling to find the arcpy Python documentation on how to use `QueryLayer`. Can you help point me in the right direction? I've updated the first line of my question for clarity.

Comment: The ArcPy command is MakeQueryLayer, available from both ArcMap and Pro installs

Comment: thanks @Vince I'll look into it and post an answer here if I can create one. I've also noticed `MakeQueryTable` which might server a similar purpose.